# Show images only from checked (checkbox) directory using PHP

Tags: php

$directory = 'uploads/mainfolder';

```
mainfolder
--subfolder1
--subfolder2
```

There will be some subfolders inside the folder 'mainfolder' ( say subfolder1, subfolder2 etc )

There should be a checkbox infront of subfolder1, subfolder2 etc..

Inside subfolder1, subfolder2 there will be some images

So as per checked and submits it should display all the images from the checked directory in the submitted page using PHP.

The script below shows all the images from the subfolder1 and subfolder2. How will i change the script to add the checkboxes and as per the checked checkboxes it should show images from that particular sub directory. Can someone pls help me on this? Thanx in advance

```
<?php
 $directory = 'uploads/mainfolder';

 foreach (glob("$directory/*") as $dir) {

 //foreach (glob('uploads/mainfolder/*') as $dir) {
   echo '<div>'; // One div per directory
  //show images
    foreach (glob($dir."/*.jpg") as $img) {
    echo "<img width='5%' src='$img'/>";
    }

 echo "</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form with checkboxes for each subdirectory inside the 'mainfolder'.
Then, when the form is submitted, get the selected checkboxes and showcase images from the chosen subdirectories.

```
<?php
$directory = 'uploads/mainfolder';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Handle form submission
    if (isset($_POST['subdirectories'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['subdirectories'] as $selectedDir) {
            $dir = $directory . '/' . $selectedDir;
            echo '<div>'; // One div per directory
            foreach (glob($dir . '/*.jpg') as $img) {
                echo "<img width='5%' src='$img'/>";
            }
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
    }
} else {
    // Display the form with checkboxes
    echo '<form method="post">';
    foreach (glob("$directory/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $subdirName = basename($dir);
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="subdirectories[]" value="' . $subdirName . '">' . $subdirName . '</label><br>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Show Images">';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes i did. Thank you.